# Turbo360 Command Line Terminal Installation Issues

Tags: terminal, node-modules

Can someone please help me I'm trying to install Turbo 360 platform (https://docs.turbo360.co) for a project I'm working on and I'm encountering so many errors in my terminal. Every time I run "$ sudo npm install turbo-cli -g" and "$ turbo version" after I get these errors in the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.3.
Node.js v13.9.0 
npm v6.13.7

I was able to find a way install it using a different command "$ npm install i turbo-cli" but when I enter the command "$ turbo version" I get the same error "-bash:turbo:command not found" screenshot below:

[image]

And no other Turbo commands works either, at this point, I've reached a wall and don't know what to do I've reached out to the Turbo team and I'm hoping for a solution but I just would like to resolve this issue so I could get back to my project. I've read when some developers have this type of problem they delete their Node_Module file and reinstall it again I'm afraid and unsure that this solution may or may not work so I don't know. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution I had to delete the turbo file in my bin folder. Had to

$ cd /usr/local/bin/

then look for turbo file

$ ls

then open turbo file

$ open .

then delete the turbo file and run

$ sudo npm install turbo-cli -g

then

$ turbo version

and it works now.